# How to disable usb port at boot time

Tags: freebsd, usb

I'm on FreeBSD 9.2. I want to disable usb port at boot time. Anyone have ideas as to how to turn off the USB?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of achieving your goal:

- You can turn USB off on `BIOS` or `UEFI` level.
- You can add `nousb` kernel parameter at boot-time.
- You can blacklist modules responsible for USB.

References:

[FreeBSD Manual Pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=usb&sektion=4)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to disable usb in kernel. so I added the line `device  nousb`, but when I rebuild the kernel, it has an error: **config: Error: device "nousb" is unknown**

Comment: "boot-time" isn't "compile time", reread the answer